# Тире или запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

*В пятницу — 3 мая — в городе произошло...*
Что здесь правильнее, тире или вместо них запятые?

Comment: Во-первых это красиво.

Comment: Вообще-то вопрос был "Что правильнее?". А что во-вторых?

Comment: Это был комментарий, вообще-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трудно представить контекст, в соответствии с которым нужно обособлять календарное число.

**Цель обособления** – это актуализация значения или уточнение.

1) **При актуализации** важное значение будет иметь  дата, с ней связано **что-то особенное**, но тогда нужно обособлять тире да еще восклицательный знак можно добавить:

*В пятницу — третьего мая! — в городе произошло...*

Но этот вариант маловероятен.

2) Это **уточнение?** Тогда важное значение будет иметь **день недели**, о нем  особая речь, а при обособлении лучше использовать запятые:

*В пятницу, **третьего мая,** в городе произошло...*

3) Если ничего этого нет, то обособление выглядит неоправданным.

Comment: Не надо ничего представлять. Надо просто посмотреть в инете - как минимум в пололвине случаев обособление присутствует.  А мотив в обем-то понятен. Автор действительно полагает подобное упоминание конкретной даты уточнением.

Comment: Хотелось бы ориентироваться на правила, а не на инет, где ошибок очень много. Я полагаю, что между числом и днем обычно равноправные отношения и знаки между ними не ставятся (это неоднородные обстоятельства).  Да и вы в ответе говорили о том же (я была с Вами согласна, поэтому на вопрос не отвечала). А вот уточняющие отношения - это вопрос интересный. В этом случае день недели более важен, чем число. Я не исключаю такую ситуацию, но какая-то интрига здесь есть.

Comment: К примеру, с точки зрения религии каждый день недели особенный. Если это так, то дата может уточнять день недели.  Но по приведенному отрывку текста  о чем-либо судить трудно. Об этом я и написала в ответе.

Comment: *Хотелось бы ориентироваться на правила* Sharon, но правила-то вам прекрасно известны. Уточнение может обособляться. Вот хотя бы http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_179. А вот есть ли тут уточнение - это уже не правила, а стилистические рекомендации. А они редко когда бывают императивны до степени запрещения.

Comment: Мне кажется, это вопрос скорее семантический. В каждой конкретной ситуации приходится решать, какой вид отношений между членами предложения. Если бы нам дали для анализа полное предложение да еще контекст, то поставить диагноз  было бы намного проще и Вам, и мне.

Comment: Sharon - ну не знаю, вы говорили, что вам трудно контекст представить, от меня жестких правил требовали на запятые, а теперь вдруг согласились, что ситуации разными бывают. Я вполне удовлетворен признанием этим.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не лучше. Оба хуже.

Ничего там не надо. Впрочем, если запятые можно хоть как-то мотивировать, то появление тире просто необъяснимо.

Comment: По контексту надо выделить, значит ставим запятые. Спасибо.